# How to make a IN query with hstore?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, hstore

I have a field (content) in a table containing keys and values (hstore) like this :

```
content: {"price"=>"15.2", "quantity"=>"3", "product_id"=>"27", "category_id"=>"2", "manufacturer_id"=>"D"}
```

I can easily select product having ONE category_id with :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE "content @> 'category_id=>27'"
```

I want to select all lines having (for example) category_id IN a list of value.

In classic SQL it would be something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE category_id IN (27, 28, 29, ....)
```

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De-reference the key and test it with `IN` as normal.

```
CREATE TABLE hstoredemo(content hstore not null);

INSERT INTO hstoredemo(content) VALUES 
('"price"=>"15.2", "quantity"=>"3", "product_id"=>"27", "category_id"=>"2", "manufacturer_id"=>"D"');
```

then one of these. The first is cleaner, as it casts the extracted value to integer rather than doing string compares on numbers.

```
SELECT * 
FROM hstoredemo 
WHERE (content -> 'category_id')::integer IN (2, 27, 28, 29);

SELECT * 
FROM hstoredemo 
WHERE content -> 'category_id' IN ('2', '27', '28', '29');
```

If you had to test more complex hstore contains operations, say with multiple keys, you could use `@> ANY`, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM hstoredemo
WHERE 
  content @> ANY(
    ARRAY[
      '"category_id"=>"27","product_id"=>"27"',
      '"category_id"=>"2","product_id"=>"27"'
    ]::hstore[]
  );
```

but it's not pretty, and it'll be a lot slower, so don't do this unless you have to.

Comment: @Sucrenoir Thank *you* for showing the SQL and data required to make this a quick and simple answer with no back and forth.

Answer (score -2):

```
category_ids = ["27", "28", "29"]
Tablename.where("category_id IN(?)", category_ids)
```